# Python function not being executed

Tags: python

Hey I'm trying to create an evaluate function for this tic-tac-toe thing that I'm doing. Basically what it does is check whether a game board (testBoard is the sample game board I created) contains any win conditions.

However, when I execute this code, nothing shows up in the terminal. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
ai = 0
player = 1
testBoard = [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]

def evaluateBoard(Board):
    # Evaluate rows
    for row in range(3):
        if Board[row][0] == Board[row][1] == Board[row][2]:
            if Board[row][0] == ai:
                return 10
            elif Board[row][0] == player:
                return -10

    # Evaluate columns
    for col in range(3):
        if Board[0][col] == Board[1][col] == Board[2][col]:
            if Board[0][col] == ai:
                return 10
            elif Board[0][col] == player:
                return -10

    # Evaluate diagonals
    if Board[0][0] == Board[1][1] == Board[2][2]:
        if Board[0][0] == ai:
            return 10
        elif Board[0][0] == player:
            return -10

    if Board[0][2] == Board[1][1] == Board[2][0]:
        if Board[0][2] == ai:
            return 10
        elif Board[0][2] == player:
            return -10

    # In case of draw, return 0
    return 0

evaluateBoard(testBoard)
```

Comment: You don't `print` anything, so nothing will show. What do you expect to see? It doesn't mean nothing ran.

Comment: You're not printing anything to the terminal, so you see nothing

Comment: Nothing will show up on screen unless you make it show up.

Comment: Note, your function probably doesn't work as you expect. As soon as you hit the first `return` you will break out of the function and none of the rest of the function body will be evaluated.

Comment: I think I assumed that return x would print x to the terminal. Thanks for clarifying that. Also, for this specific function I do want it to stop evaluating the rest of the function as soon as it hits a valid return.

Comment: @NeilShah yeah, then simply `print(evaluateBoard(testBoard))`. Python generally won't do something unless you tell it to, like printing. In the case of an interactive session, well, that's why it's called a *R*ead-*E*valuate-**P**rint-*L*oop. Quite literally, indeed, an interactive session could be pretty much written as `while True: result = input(">>> "); print(eval(result))` with a little bit of handling and special cases...

Comment: Yes, breaking out makes sense actually considering the context is tic-tac-toe, I was being slow sorry :) Printing to terminal is very expensive (if you had thousands of function calls your program would run _orders of magnitude_ slower) and really annoying, so be glad it doesn't work like that :P

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement returns the value to the interpreter (or a variable if you're assigning the output of the function to a variable); it doesn't do anything with it unless you specify it.

You can modify your function where it says `return` to say `print(10)` or whatever value you want.

You can also do the following:

```
result = evaluateBoard(testBoard)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no prints in the code. Try:

```
print evaluateBoard(testBoard)
```

Or if you are using Python3

```
print(evaluateBoard(testBoard))
```

Remember that if you are executing the entire file you won't see the same behavior as executing Python code inside the command line of the interpreter. To see outputs you have to send something on the standard output.